# Temporary Dead Zone in ES6 playground?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am reading **Nicholas Zakas**' [Understanding ECMAScript 6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593277571) and on Chapter 1 he mentioned about `Temporary Dead Zone` aka **TDZ**, wherein accessing a `let` variable within a block will generate an error but outside it will only be regarded as `undefined`. Find below is a combined code that I made out of his sample code with his own comments:

```js
console.log(typeof value); // "undefined"

if (condition) {
  console.log(typeof value); // throws an error
  let value = "blue";
}
```

I tried the same code at [Mike Lambert's ES6 playground](http://mikelambert.me/es6/) but it showed both `console.log` as `undefined` and no error. So, my question is Mr Zakas wrong or is Mike Lambert's ES6 playground **transpiled** to `ES5` at the background?

Comment: Probably the latter, since the browser console directly works as expected (TDZ behaviour).

Comment: ES6 playground does use a transpiler. If you want to try out ES6 these days, just use the console of a recent browser, they all do support it.

Comment: "*is Mike Lambert's ES6 playground transpiled to ES5*" Yes, it is. The playground includes a panel that can show you the transpiled ES5 (which substitutes `let` with `var`). It can be shown/hidden using some of the buttons in the top bar (ES6, ES5, Console).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. @JonathanLonowski, yes I saw that one and I only selected `ES6` to be safe and yet the result was both `undefined`.

Comment: @Edper The buttons only appear to be visibility toggles. Switching off ES5 doesn't stop it from transpiling before evaluating the ES6 you enter. (You can watch the CodeMirror editor for ES5 continue to update as you change the ES6 from your browser's developer tools.)

Comment: A ok. Thanks @JonathanLonowski. I saw an error though as you mentioned when I view it in the browser's developer tools. I am using Chrome by the way on Mac. Well, I am new to this one and was experimenting as I read along. My first thinking, when I saw the result, is that if there are changes on `ES6` right after he published the book. Thus, I have to confirmed from experts here. Do you have by the way recommendation for an pure ES6 playground without any transpilation? Sorry, for this newbie question. Thanks again to all who answers.